# C# List<string> to JSON objects

Tags: c#, json

I have a list of strings, printing out:

> ["TEST1","TEST2","TEST3"]

How would I go about transforming this data to this JSON formatting?

> [
> {
> "value": "TEST1"
> },
> {
> "value": "TEST2"
> },
> {
> "value": "TEST3"
> }
> ]

I do not plan on creating an object.

Have tried using dictionary and key value pairs as well.

Comment: Well, why not using a class when your json is clearly a list of objects ? Are there any special reasons ? It looks like an XY problem to me

Comment: Thanks All!!! I will consider creating an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
List<string> tests = new List<string> { "TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3"};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( tests.Select( t=> new { value = t }));
```

but I highly recommend to create a class

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( tests.Select( t => new Test { value = t}));

   // or if you are using System.Text.Json
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(tests.Select(  t=>n ew Test { value = t }));
    
public class Test
{
    public string value {get; set;}
}
```

json

```
[{"value":"TEST1"},{"value":"TEST2"},{"value":"TEST3"}]
```

Comment: The OP specifically said they do not want to create an object for this serialization case.

Comment: @DavidL He also said "Have tried using dictionary and key value pairs as well."

Comment: A dictionary is not going to work, Dictionaries don't like repeated key values.

Answer (score 2):

What about this ?

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new [] {"TEST1","TEST2","TEST3" };
        var str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list.Select(l => new { Value = l }));
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically the same as the others, but using a `foreach`:

```
public static string[] TestArray = new[] { "TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", };

public static string Test()
{
    var data = new List<object>(TestArray.Length);
    foreach (var item in TestArray)
    {
        data.Add(new { @value = item });
    }
    var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
    return result;
}
```

Gives:

```
[
  {
    "value": "TEST1"
  },
  {
    "value": "TEST2"
  },
  {
    "value": "TEST3"
  }
]
```

It uses `System.Text.Json`, but it should get the same result if you use the Newtonsoft serializer.

Comment: This is great thank you - I was avoiding using Newtonsoft so I will try this as well.